# Filter specific parts of a log file

Tags: text-processing, logs

I need to filter the mail-log to send reports to me everyday, so I can track blocked addresses easily.

This is part of the log:

```
Oct  2 14:22:49 mail postfix/smtp/smtpd[3401121]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from cloud831541.educacaa.com.br[45.140.41.93]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [45.140.41.93] blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net; Currently Sending Spam See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?45.140.41.93; from=<planfranciely-fe@educacaa.com.br> to=<leonardo@home-server> proto=ESMTP helo=<cloud831541.educacaa.com.br>
Oct  2 14:26:02 mail postfix/smtp/smtpd[3403329]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from ws21763.adcote.com.br[185.249.200.83]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Helo command [ws217632.adcote.com.br] blocked using dbl.spamhaus.org; https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/adcote.com.br; from=<adrinoworkshop-5i@adcote.com.br> to=<leonardo@home-server> proto=ESMTP helo=<ws217632.adcote.com.br>
Oct  2 14:43:51 mail postfix/smtp/smtpd[3403329]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from o12.mailer.shopify.com[149.72.90.155]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [149.72.90.155] blocked using spam.dnsbl.sorbs.net; Spam Received See: http://www.sorbs.net/lookup.shtml?149.72.90.155; from=<bounces+12398229-c901-leonardo=home-server.net.br@mailer.shopifyemail.com> to=<leonardo@home-server> proto=ESMTP helo=<o12.mailer.shopify.com>
```

I need to cut from `RCPT from` until `:` and before `554 5.7.1` and also print from `blocked using` until `;` before `Currently Sending`.

So the output would be something like this =

```
RCPT from cloud831541.educacaa.com.br[45.140.41.93] -- blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net
```

A way easier to check who was blocked by my mail filters.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if the following long-ish `sed` substitution may do what you want.

```bsh
sed -n 's/.*\(RCPT from[^:]*\):.*554 5\.7\.1.*\(blocked using[^;]*\);.*Currently Sending.*/\1 -- \2/p' file
```

It is doing what you said by capturing the two bits of the lines you wanted using `\(...\)` twice.  We're mainly using various static strings to anchor the regular expression to the line, and if any bit does not match, `sed` will not output the line.  The expressions `[^:]*` and `[^;]*` will match any (possibly empty) substring that does not contain a `:` or `;`, respectively, and `.*` matches any substring whatsoever.

If all of the expression matches we replace the whole line using the two collected substrings and a double dash, and we output the modified line.

The result, given the data in the question, will be a single line.

```
RCPT from cloud831541.educacaa.com.br[45.140.41.93] -- blocked using dnsbl.sorbs.net
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Could I add the date/time of the grep log? Eg.:
Oct  2 14:43:51 -- RCPT from ...

Comment: @LeonardoL.Southier We're not using `grep`. To capture the first part of the line, before `mail`: `sed -n 's/^\(.*\) mail.*\(RCPT from[^:]*\):.*554 5\.7\.1.*\(blocked using[^;]*\);.*Currently Sending.*/\1 -- \2 -- \3/p' file`  I'm sure you can see how this is done now and can do further refinements by yourself.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Sorry for changing commands, when I wrote grep I mean sed haha.
Your command works just fine, thank you.